# Hide Divs on POST Request AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, .net-6.0, razor-pages

I get the ID value I need from the URL, when I click on the Department Name I want the values to autofill on the textboxes instead of having the extra div. I also need the Divs to hide when the POST request is submitted, currently the page refreshes on post revealing the divs. Another issue I'm having is that when I click Submit, I need the last 4 numbers of the social to be masked for security purposes. If possible have an eye icon to reveal the full value.

index.cshtml

```
@page "{id?}"
@model IndexModel
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; }

<form method="get">
    <div id="DepartmentResult"></div>&nbsp;
    <div id="EmployeeResult"></div>
</form>

<form method="post">
    <label>Department Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="DeptName" />
    <label>Photo File Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="NameResult" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <input type="text" id="social" />
</form>

@section Scripts {
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/Index?handler=DisplayDepartment",
            type: "GET",
            data: { value: @Model.Id },
            headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            success: function(data) { $("#DepartmentResult").html(data); }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

_DisplayDepartmentPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Department>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
 {
    <div id="EmployeeSection">
        <table style="border: 1px solid black">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">Department Results</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DepartmentName)</td></tr>

                @foreach (Models.Department item in Model)
                 {
                    <tr><td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center"><a href="Index?handler=DisplayEmployee&value=@item.DepartmentName">@item.DepartmentName</a></td></tr>
                 }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
 }
else
{
    <p>No data</p>
}

<script>
    $('#EmployeeSection a').click(function(event) {
        $('#EmployeeResult').hide().load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
            $('#EmployeeResult').show()
        })
        return false
    })
</script>
```

_DisplayEmployeePartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Employee>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
 {
    <table style="border: 1px solid black">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">Employee Results</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold;">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.EmployeeName)
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DepartmentName)
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.PhotoFileName)
                </td>
            </tr>

            @foreach (Models.Employee item in Model)
             {
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        <a>@item.EmployeeName</a>
                        <a>@item.DepartmentName</a>
                        <a>@item.PhotoFileName</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
 }
else
{
    <p>No data</p>
}
```

index.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using PracticeApp.Models;
using System.Linq;

namespace PracticeApp.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public CompanyContext _context;

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] public int Id { get; set; }

        public IndexModel(CompanyContext context) { _context = context; }

        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayDepartment(int value) => Partial("_DisplayDepartmentPartial", _context.Departments.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == value).ToList());
        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayEmployee(string value) => Partial("_DisplayEmployeePartial", _context.Employees.Where(x => x.DepartmentName == value).GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeName).Select(x => x.First()).ToList());
    }
}
```

Employee model.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PracticeApp.Models
{
    public partial class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string? EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; } = null!;
        public DateTime? DateofJoining { get; set; }
        public string? PhotoFileName { get; set; }
        public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string? Ssn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Which div would you like to hide? Do you want to hide it after you click "IT" to initiate a post request? @TheGame1083

Comment: I don't have it here in the code, but I would use a button with type submit to initiate the POST request

Comment: Which method do you want to make a post request to via submit? Which div to hide?

Comment: DepartmentResult Div

Comment: @Chen I've added additional code just in case

Answer (score 0):

You can hide this div directly when you click Submit.

For example, I add a form in `_DisplayDepartmentPartial` to query the employees of "IT":

```
<form asp-page-handler="DisplayEmployee" method="post">
      <input id="value" name="value"/>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    $("form").submit(function(e){
        $("#DepartmentResult").hide();
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "Index?handler=DisplayEmployee",
                type: "POST",
                data: { value: $("#value").text()},
                headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                success: function(data) { $("#EmployeeResult").html(data); }
            });
    })
</script>
```

Result:

Enter "IT":

[image]

Click Submit:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Chen, it's still not working for me. I have 2 forms on my page, one to get data and one to post data. When I click submit on my post form my get form is still appearing because of the get Ajax method which ai need only when the page loads at the beginning, I do not need it on post request, anyway I can contact you?

Comment: I seem to understand what you mean. You call the get method on page load and then the post method reloads the page, right? Does your post method add the data in an empty div? If it is, you can judge whether it is empty to decide whether to call the get request.

Comment: It would be better if you would provide the code you tried. @TheGame1083

Comment: code provided @Chen

Comment: Hi, @TheGame1083, I replied to you in [your new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502415/trying-to-autofill-values-to-input-textbox/74515038#74515038), you can try it.