# Trying to Autofill values to input textbox

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, razor-pages

I get the ID value I need from the URL, when I click on the Department Name I want the values to autofill on the textboxes instead of having the extra div. I also need the Divs to hide when the POST request is submitted, currently the page refreshes on post revealing the divs. Another issue I'm having is that when I click Submit, I need the last 4 numbers of the social to be masked for security purposes. If possible have an eye icon to reveal the full value.

index.cshtml

```
@page "{id?}"
@model IndexModel
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; }

<form method="get">
    <div id="DepartmentResult"></div>&nbsp;
    <div id="EmployeeResult"></div>
</form>

<form method="post">
    <label>Department Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="DeptName" />
    <label>Photo File Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="NameResult" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <input type="text" id="social" />
</form>

@section Scripts {
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/Index?handler=DisplayDepartment",
            type: "GET",
            data: { value: @Model.Id },
            headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            success: function(data) { $("#DepartmentResult").html(data); }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

_DisplayDepartmentPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Department>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
 {
    <div id="EmployeeSection">
        <table style="border: 1px solid black">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">Department Results</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DepartmentName)</td></tr>

                @foreach (Models.Department item in Model)
                 {
                    <tr><td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center"><a href="Index?handler=DisplayEmployee&value=@item.DepartmentName">@item.DepartmentName</a></td></tr>
                 }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
 }
else
{
    <p>No data</p>
}

<script>
    $('#EmployeeSection a').click(function(event) {
        $('#EmployeeResult').hide().load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
            $('#EmployeeResult').show()
        })
        return false
    })
</script>
```

_DisplayEmployeePartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Employee>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
 {
    <table style="border: 1px solid black">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">Employee Results</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold;">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.EmployeeName)
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DepartmentName)
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.PhotoFileName)
                </td>
            </tr>

            @foreach (Models.Employee item in Model)
             {
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        <a>@item.EmployeeName</a>
                        <a>@item.DepartmentName</a>
                        <a>@item.PhotoFileName</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
 }
else
{
    <p>No data</p>
}
```

index.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using PracticeApp.Models;
using System.Linq;

namespace PracticeApp.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public CompanyContext _context;

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] public int Id { get; set; }

        public IndexModel(CompanyContext context) { _context = context; }

        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayDepartment(int value) => Partial("_DisplayDepartmentPartial", _context.Departments.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == value).ToList());
        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayEmployee(string value) => Partial("_DisplayEmployeePartial", _context.Employees.Where(x => x.DepartmentName == value).GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeName).Select(x => x.First()).ToList());
    }
}
```

Employee model.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PracticeApp.Models
{
    public partial class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string? EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; } = null!;
        public DateTime? DateofJoining { get; set; }
        public string? PhotoFileName { get; set; }
        public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string? Ssn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data via ajax request to populate the corresponding text:

_DisplayDepartmentPartial.cshtml:

```
@if (Model.Count() != 0)
{
    <div id="EmployeeSection">
        <table style="border: 1px solid black">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">Department Results</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name)</td></tr>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr><td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center"><a onclick="Test()" href="#">@item.Name</a></td></tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <p>No data</p>
}

<script>

    function Test()
    {
        $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "Index?handler=DisplayEmployee",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { value: $('#EmployeeSection a').text()},
                    dataType: "json",
                    headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#DeptName").val(data[0].departmentName);
                        $("#NameResult").val(data[0].name);

                    }
                });
    }
```

Regarding hidden data, you can refer to the following code：

```
<input type="text" id="social" /><i class="iconfont icon-eye-fill" id="eye"></i>
@section Scripts {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://at.alicdn.com/t/font_3448045_gwooawlcz3s.css">
    <script>
        var trueVal = ""; 
        var newVal = ""; 
        var flag = false;

        $("#social").bind("input propertychange", function (e) {
            var val = $("#social").val();
            trueVal += e.originalEvent.data;
            if (val?.length >= 5) {
                newVal = val.slice(0, val.length - 1) + "*";
                $("#social").val(newVal);
            }
        })
        $("#eye").on('click', function () {
            if (flag == false) {
                $("#social").val(trueVal);
                flag = true;
                $("#eye").attr("class", "iconfont icon-eye-fill");
            } else {
                $("#social").val(newVal);
                flag = false;
                $("#eye").attr("class", "iconfont icon-no_eye");
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

I'm not sure where your post request is pointing, and what you're doing with it, so if you want to hide the div by submitting, you can refer to the following two ways:

The first one:

Add an id to the post form,and then:

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
            $("#DepartmentResult").hide();
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax(
                {
                });
        })
```

Use `e.preventDefault();` then your page will not refresh.

The second one:

Use a parameter to decide whether to call ajax on page load:

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string Exist { get; set; } = "NotExist";
//your post method
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostMethod(your param)
{
     Exist = "Existed";
     //other code   
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            if ("@Model.Exist" == "NotExist") {
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: "/Index?handler=DisplayDepartment",
                        type: "Get",
                        data: { value: @Model.Id },
                        headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                        success: function (data) { $("#DepartmentResult").html(data); }
                    });
            }else{
                $("#DepartmentResult").hide();
            }
        })
```

Hope this can help you.